# CODEIGNITER : How to acces method inside a library that contain many classes

Tags: php, codeigniter

as the title say 
 i had filename.php file inside application/libraries

this file contain many class, and every class have at least 1 method. how I do access these method?

because in codeigniter example only assume 1 class for 1 file.

thanks^^

Comment: I read this thread with the same problem : http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-54993.html , he said separate the class to each file. Then you can create helper that loads all the classes.

Comment: @reignsly wow this is what i've been looking for. thanks bro^^

Answer (score 0):

You can't define a class in another class. include your class before

```
//application/libraries/class1.php
//application/libraries/class2.php
//application/libraries/class3.php
require_once('class1.php');
require_once('class2.php');
require_once('class3.php');

class NewLib
{
    public function class1()
    {
       return new Class1();
    }
    public function class2()
    {
       return new Class2();
    } 
    public function class3()
    {
       return new Class3();
    } 
}

$this->load->library('NewLib');

$class1 = $this->newlib->class1();
$class1->something();
```